# Square foot garden companion planting - in occupied squares or not?

Tags: square-foot-gardening

This is our 5th year using about 160 square feet of garden space. We have never really played with companion planting though. We have several zucchini (16 squares, 4x4), squash (2x2), tomatoes (2x2), peppers (~2x2), etc.

When you are companion planting in a square foot garden, are you able to plant the companion crop in the squares that are occupied by the larger plant - could I plant a bunch of radishes and nasturtiums in the 16 square feet taken up by the 4x4 of the zucchini? Can I plant carrots in the 4 squares taken up by a tomato plant with the tomato in the center?

This would seem to be correct way since beans were grown at the base of corn and use the stalks as a pole...

Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you rotating your crops as well? I always cram plants together and as long as I watch for nutrient deficiencies, insect problems, fungal diseases and catch things early, I think plants like the closeness. Plant likes with likes.  Similar moisture, pH, fertilizer needs, think about big plants shading the smaller ones...

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can, but may need to play around with timing and spacing a bit. I often plant radishes around larger plants like zucchini in my raised beds. By the time the zuke is taking up most of the space allotted to it, the radishes are long gone. With plants like tomatoes and carrots, which both stay in most of the season, you may need to adjust the spacing a bit, to give them both enough space. That's all part of the fun, though - figuring out what adjustments work for you and your garden.